# ISNULL/COALESCE counterpart for values that are not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-function

Is there a function that is similar to `COALESCE` but for values that are not `NULL`?

I need to replace a return value of a scalar-valued-function with another value if it returns the string literal `N/A`. If it would return `NULL` i could use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(dbo.GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut(RMA.IMEI), RMA.IMEI) AS [IMEI to credit]
     , OtherColumns
FROM dbo.TableName
```

But since it returns `N/A` this doesn't work. I could also use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut(RMA.IMEI)='N/A' 
         THEN RMA.IMEI 
         ELSE dbo.GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut(RMA.IMEI)
       END AS [IMEI To Credit]         
    , OtherColumns
FROM dbo.TableName
```

But that would be inefficient since it needs to execute the function twice per record.

Note that this query is in a table-valued-function.

Comment: But can't you just modify the function `GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut` itself to return NULL instead of N/A ?

Comment: @StephenByrne: That would cause other problems/work. So i've asked first if there is a way to solve this without the "breaking change". The method is already used in some excel addins that i would have to modify  then.

Comment: What about creating another function that wraps `GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut` and changes N/A to `NULL`? Doing that, you could use `COALESCE` and still have only one call to `GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps there you can use [NULLIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) function, for example:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(dbo.GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut(RMA.IMEI), 'N/A'), RMA.IMEI) AS [IMEI to credit]
     , OtherColumns
FROM dbo.TableName;
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter - This may well execute the function twice anyway. [`ISNULL` is generally better than `COALESCE` for this.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Really, why? Can i prevent that in some way?

Comment: See the connect item linked above. If the plan shows the function referenced twice because of how `COALESCE` gets expanded to `CASE` then you can replace `COALESCE` with `ISNULL`

Comment: I changed COALESCE to ISNULL (I personally use ISNULL in most cases)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Interesting, thanks for the info. I normally use `COALESCE` everywhere. Easy to reproduce the bug since `SELECT coalesce(xyz, 0) FROM sys.objects` produces two errors instead of one.

Comment: I use COALESCE only in cases when count of parameters > 2

Comment: @Andrey: Why (apart from this reason)? `COALESCE` is ANSI standard as opposed to `ISNULL`.

Comment: The isnull function requires exactly 2 argument(s), but COALESCE can accept more than 2 parameters

Comment: Seems that `COALESCE` always gets expanded to `CASE`. Was an eye opener for me! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: OMG! I did't know that! Thanx!

Comment: @StephenByrne: Thanks for the link to MSDN which also mentions this behaviour: _"This means that the input values (expression1, expression2, expressionN, etc.) will be evaluated multiple times. Also, in compliance with the SQL standard, a value expression that contains a **subquery** is considered non-deterministic and the subquery **is evaluated twice**. In either case, different results can be returned between the first evaluation and subsequent evaluations.  For example, when the code COALESCE((subquery), 1) is executed, the subquery **is evaluated twice** .... "_

Comment: @TimSchmelter - it's amazing what we learn when we RTFM :) I used `COALESCE` all the time up until today, purely because I thought I was being cool with my "ANSI Compatible" SQL...so thanks to *you* for the question that led to this revelation for me!

Answer (score 5):

If you can't change `GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut` to return Null-Values then try this:

`SELECT COALESCE(dbo.GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut(NULLIF(RMA.IMEI, 'N/A')), RMA.IMEI) AS [IMEI to credit]
     , OtherColumns
FROM dbo.TableName`

Comment: Thanks to all, you were the fastest, but Andrey's answer contains the the function and link i've searched. I have upvoted all three anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The function nullif returns null if its arguments are equal, and its first argument otherwise. Combine with coalesce for fun and profit:

```
select
    coalesce(
        nullif(dbo.GetFirstSsnInFromSsnOut(RMA.IMEI), 'N/A'),
        RMA.IMEI
    ) as [IMEI To Credit]
    , OtherColumns
from dbo.TableName
```